# How to pass a variable as a column name with pyodbc?

Tags: python, pyodbc

I have a list that has two phone numbers and I'd like to put each phone number into its own column in an Access database. The column names are Phone_Number1 and Phone_Number2. How do I pass that to the INSERT statement?

```py
phone_numbers = ['###.218.####', '###.746.####']

driver = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}'
filepath = 'C:/Users/Notebook/Documents/master.accdb'
myDataSources = pyodbc.dataSources()
access_driver = myDataSources['MS Access Database']

conn = pyodbc.connect(driver=driver, dbq=filepath)
cursor = conn.cursor()

phone_number_count = 1
for phone_number in phone_numbers:
    column_name = "Phone_Number" + str(phone_number_count)
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Business_Cards (column_name) VALUES (?)", (phone_number))

conn.commit()
print("Your database has been updated.")
```

This is what I have so far.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Notebook/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/BusinessCard.py", line 55, in <module>
    database_entry(phone_numbers, emails, name, title)
  File "C:/Users/Notebook/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/BusinessCard.py", line 47, in database_entry
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Business_Cards (column_name) VALUES (?)", (phone_number))
pyodbc.Error: ('HYS22', "[HYS22] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: 'column_name'. Make sure you have typed the name correctly, and try the operation again. (-1507) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Comment: Try formatting the string: `cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO Business_Cards ({column_name}) VALUES (?)", (phone_number))`

Comment: Yes. That helped. Now I'm faced with the problem that each row iteration is on a separate row as the cursor.execute completes the row entry. I need them both on the same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert both numbers in the same row, remove the for loop and adjust the `INSERT` to consider the two columns:

```py
phone_numbers = ['###.218.####', '###.746.####']
# ...
column_names = [f"PhoneNumber{i}" for i in range(1, len(phone_numbers) + 1)]
placeholders = ['?'] * len(phone_numbers)
cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO Business_Cards ({', '.join(column_names)}) VALUES ({', '.join(placeholders)})", tuple(phone_numbers))

conn.commit()
# ...
```

Comment: That helps in this case, but if I'm pulling in a list of phone numbers and there's more than 2? How do I do it dynamically? Your first suggestion worked except for needing them in the same row. I've been trying to do an update statement but I can't get the syntax to work.

Comment: @BrandonJacobson I adjust the answer to make the insert dynamic according to the `phone_numbers` list length.